# Creating private nameservers, registrar has no idea how

Tags: dns, private, nameservers, registrar

i have registered a domain under the extension .al (albania). But in my domain panel there is no option to create my own nameservers. I have asked them to do this for me but they seem confused and dont know how to do it.

I'm sure there must be a way though. Could someone tell me what they need to do so i pass this info to them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change the registrar. For example, I have the option to specify my own domain servers (registrar: nic.ru, domain in .su zone).